# Ubuntu Apache: "Module php7 does not exist"

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to upgrade PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 7 on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I've read many tutorials and articles how to do it, but each of them misses something. For example, somewhere they say you must `sudo a2dismod php5` then `sudo a2enmod php7`. The problem is that I always get this message

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7
ERROR: Module php7 does not exist!
```

Does someone one how to resolve this problem, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the official tutorial about this. Have you read it? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I think you will need to do sudo apt-get install php7.0 before this command your are running.

Comment: This is the first tutorial I've read, and yes already `sudo apt-get install php7.0`. :/ I really have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: Next ste is checking if the module was really installed. I don't know exactly where PHP modules are stored in Ubuntu, but a little google research will tell us.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, apache modules are in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`, and after `sudo a2enmod` they are present in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` also. I found there two PHP 5 files: `php5.conf` and `php5.load`, but no presence of PHP 7.

Comment: For those who downvote, you could at least explain why you do so. :/

Comment: Your question does not follow the guidelines for questions on StackOverflow. Try to reword it thinking in terms of how others might have the same problem.

Comment: I don't care if this question is "off topic", I'm glad it was here! I did a lot of searching before finding this and immediately solved my problem. Also, this comment is probably off topic, feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Finally, thanks to the comment of Ed de Almeida, I found the solution.

I had to install an additional package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Now I could run `sudo a2enmod php7.0`.

Comment: Good to know that I helped a bit. Congratulations and good development!

Comment: Thanks Its working

Comment: Thank you, helped me out. I wonder why this is not included in the php7 package.

Comment: thanks, should mark as correct answer

Comment: Thanks, its working

Comment: to me this says " Impossible to find package libapache2-mod-php7.0"

Comment: I am not able to get this to work : `E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php7.0' has no installation candidate`

Comment: I already had `libapache2-mod-php7.0` installed, but `a2enmod` complained that `ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!` Removing the mod package and reinstalling fixed the problem.

Comment: Please run following command :

`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0`

Basically that is to change terminal (cli) version

Comment: See this post on Ask Ubuntu that contains a more current answer for `libapache2-mod-php7.4`, https://askubuntu.com/a/1294488/326349 which describes a couple of steps that involve using `apt purge` to clean up then `apt-get` to install the the module needed.