# How to install module php7.3 for apache 2.4.18

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I have different versions of `Php 7.0, 7.2, 7.3` installed on `ubuntu 16.04`.

In terminal if I type `php -v`, it shows like

```
PHP 7.3.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 11:06:26) ( NTS )
```

But in my `localhost url`, on printing `phpinfo()`

```
PHP Version 7.0.33-8+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

When I try to switch to `v-7.3` using  `sudo a2enmod php7.3`
it gives error

> ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!

I checked with `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*`, it gives like

> /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.conf 
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load

Then I tried to install `apache2 module for php 7.3 like`

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

it gives

> libapache2-mod-php7.3 is already the newest version
>   (7.3.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)

Any hints what could be wrong here.

I used below ref

https://askubuntu.com/questions/912638/error-module-php7-0-does-not-exist
[Ubuntu Apache: "Module php7 does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057615/ubuntu-apache-module-php7-does-not-exist)

**EDIT:**

If I run `sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.3`

> Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64
>   php7.3-fpm amd64 7.3.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1   403  Forbidden
>   E: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-fpm_7.3.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
>   403  Forbidden E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get
>   update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Exists the module? Check it with `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/php*`

Comment: it gives `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.load`

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.3` and then `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3`. Then check again if the mod appears in the folder, if it appears then, run the `sudo a2enmod ...` command followed by `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: for 1st command got issues, pls see my edit