# htaccess to allow php 8 to execute in html files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, php-8

`ubuntu 22.04.1 LST, Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu), PHP 8.1.2`

I'm doing this on my local computer, not on an actual web-server.  I'm going through this just to do it and see how it is done.

I've installed `apache2` on my computer which is running `Ubuntu`. I also have `PHP8.1` installed.  I followed a couple of tutorials on setting up `apache2` on Ubuntu.  Everything works fine except I can't get the `.htaccess` entry correct to allow `php` to run inside my `html` files. I've done some `apache .conf` and `.htaccess` stuff before but am definitely a beginner.

```
my .conf file:

<Directory /var/www/johndcowan/public_html>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

```
my .htaccess file:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php8 .html
```

```
My test index.html file:

<html>
  <head>
    <title> Ubuntu rocks! </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>I'm running this website on an Ubuntu Server server!</p>               
   
    <?php print "<p>This is printed with php tags</p>"; ?>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load my webpage I see this:

```
I'm running this website on an Ubuntu Server server!
This is printed with php tags
"; ?>
```

So, it's not displaying the `<?php print "` but it is showing the rest of the php code.

I haven't been able to find any info on using `php8` or `php81` in the `.htaccess` file.  I've tried using different versions, but none work:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .html
```

The setup is seeing my `.htaccess` file. If I change the `AddHandler` to an `AddType` and reload my test page, I get prompted to `Save or Download` the page.

Any thoughts on what I can do/try differently?

Any help is appreciated.

****** UPDATED AFTER SOLVING ******

I Googled on "How to enable PHP in apache2".  It led me to a thread on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057615/ubuntu-apache-module-php7-does-not-exist

I had to install a php module package and enable a php-module-8.1, then this worked.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
... 
# in the output I saw this line:
apache2_invoke: Enable module php8.1
```

Then, just to be sure, I ran:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php8.1
...
# and I saw this line in the outpu:
Module php8.1 already enabled
```

*Note* I tried to install specific versions of the mod-php package but I kept getting a `E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php8` The same error for `mod-php7` and `mod-php5`.  Using just the generic `...mod-php` worked and it knew to get the `8.1` version.

I reloaded my webpage and it worked as expected.

Comment: Did you inspect the generated markup? Is PHP running after all?

Comment: @Nico Haase - thanks, but I'm not sure I follow you. Do I need to tell apache (conf file) I'm running php?

Comment: did u try this AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

Comment: first find your correct handler using $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER']

Comment: @user1844933 The issue is solved. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Googled on "How to enable php in apache2".  I found a thread on Stackoverflow: [Ubuntu Apache: "Module php7 does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057615/ubuntu-apache-module-php7-does-not-exist)

It led me to run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
...
# in the output I saw this line:
apache2_invoke: Enable module php8.1
```

Then, just in case, I ran the following to enable php8.1 module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php8.1
...
Module php8.1 already enabled
```

I reloaded my webpage and it works great as expected now.